# Read from Kafka Topic and store the data into a list using Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am reading from a kafka topic and doing some data processing actions such as removing unnecessary characters and urls and then want to generate a list from the dataframe and do further data analysis part using dataframe structure. Finally I want to write the final result into a new Kafka topic

```
val readStream = existingSparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("subscribe", "myTopic.raw") 
      .load()

//do some preprocessing tasks

val myDataframe = preprocessing()

val finalDataframe
//convert dataframe into a list

val x = myDataframe.toDF()
    val myList =   x.select("value").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList
for(element <- myList) {


 finalDataframe =  dataAnalysis(element)
}

//write back to kafka

val writeStream = finalDataframe 
     .writeStream
     .outputMode("append")
     .format("kafka")
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
     .option("topic", "myRaw.test")
     .start()
     writeStream.awaitAnyTermination()
```

But with this I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
> writeStream.start()

Comment: You don´t need to convert your dataframe to a string to publish to Kafka. Furthermore, the rdd action is not supported in Spark Structured Streaming. All the transformations can be executed inside a Spark ML Pipeline, or you can use UDFs... What does your dataAnalysis do?

Comment: You should put dataAnalysis function inside the map function, not collect data to the Spark driver then loop over it, and if you really just want to write to another Kafka topic, Kafka Streams would be easier than Spark

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 will be checking for smileys and categorize them into certain groups and finally writing the labelled dataframe into a kafka topic

Comment: add the code to see how could it be done using spark transformations